# Missing SELECT statement using QueryDSL with Spring QueryDslJdbcTemplate causing bad SQL Grammar error

Tags: spring, spring-data, querydsl

I'm using Spring Data JDBC Extensions 1.0.0 and QueryDSL 2.9.0 to do a simple query from my database.

My query is created like:

```
        QFaq qFaq = QFaq.faq;
    SQLQuery sqlQuery = jdbcTemplate.newSqlQuery().from(qFaq);
    return jdbcTemplate.query(sqlQuery, new FaqRowMapper());
```

The problem is that the SQL code that's generated is just

```
from FAQ FAQ
```

It's missing a SELECT * at the beginning.

Using an Oracle DB if that matters.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't provide any items for the select part. I assume that you use this method

```
query(com.mysema.query.sql.SQLQuery sqlQuery, RowMapper<T> rowMapper, com.mysema.query.types.Expression<?>... projection)
```

After the query and rowMapper you need to provide the expressions for the select part, e.g. qFaq.id, qFaq.name etc.

Comment: Thanks,  Timo!  I read both the QueryDSL and Spring Data JDBC docs several times, and missed that every time.  I appreciate the help!